# How can I embed a specific Tweet but still style it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, tweets, oembed

I want to embed a Tweet with a specific tweet ID. I know you can use the 'Embed This Tweet' option to get pre-rendered HTML but I want to be able to style the tweet and have more control. How would this be possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Use an ajax request with twitter's oEmbed endpoint: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets